# How to reflect another site in my site using URL Rewriting?

Tags: linux, windows, .htaccess, url-rewriting, isapi

I think my doubt is simple, but I could not find the answer.

I have a linux server that hosts the domain http://www.DomainOne.com
And I have a second server based in Windows plataform that hosts the domain http://www.DomainTwo.com

What I want to do is: When I access the DomainOne.com, it shows all contents of DomainTwo.com, but WITHOUT redirecting the page.

In this case, if I access DomainOne.com/defaultPage.asp?Attribute=test&foo=bar
the URL in browser will be exatly this url, but, the URL showed to the user will be
DomainTwo.com/defaultPage.asp?Attribute=test&foo=bar

Is it possible?

I can't move my pages from DomainTwo to DomainOne because my pages is based in ASP, that works just in Windows. Than, I think that the only solution is to reflect my URL in the original one.

Thanks Guys.

Comment: Not possible without using a proxy and it would be a question for: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @AndySchmitt: If you're ready to enable `mod_proxy` on `DomainOne.com` then it would be possible. Let me know if you are ready to do this.

Comment: @anubhava Yes, I can use mod_proxy on DomainOne.com :)

Answer (score 0):

On `DomainOne.com` enable `mod_rewrite`, **`mod_proxy`** and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?DomainOne\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://DomainOne.com%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L]
```